# toolbar and intellisense not showing

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Windows 10.

The version of the notebook server is: 6.0.2

Python: 3.8.1

1. How do I enable the toolbar with run commands? Every tutorial I watch has this toolbar.
2. How do I enable IntelliSense? Tutorials all have it and it looks sweet.

[image: wheres the toolbar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Jupyter Labs to see the toolbar. Jupyter notebooks doesnt have it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can activate the [Runtools](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/runtools/readme.html) extension from the [Jupyter notebook extensions](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions).
2. What about the [Hinterland](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/hinterland/README.html) extension either?